A question of the conclusion stating that if A is a rank-1 matrix and $tr(A)≠0$，then its eigenvalues must be $n - 1$ zeros and one tr(A).
There is a conclusion stating that if A is a rank-1 matrix and $tr(A)≠0$，then its eigenvalues must be $n - 1$ zeros and one tr(A).
But I have a question about this. If we let $A=\alpha\beta^T$, where $\alpha=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)^T$ and $\beta=$
$(b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n})^{T}$,and both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-zero vectors, then we have
$$A^3=\alpha(\beta^T\alpha\beta^T\alpha)\beta^T=\mathrm{tr}^2(A)A.$$
If I assume $AX=\lambda X$ where $X\neq0$,then we have $A^3X=\lambda^3X.$
According to the above, we also have $A^3X=\mathrm{tr}^2(A)AX=\mathrm{tr}^2(A)\lambda X.$
Thus, $\lambda^3X=\mathrm{tr}^2(A)\lambda X$, i.e, $(\lambda^3-\mathrm{tr}^2(A)\lambda)X=0$, 
and since $X\neq0$, it follows that $\lambda^3-$
$\mathrm{tr}^2(A)\lambda=0$, giving $\lambda=0,\lambda=$tr$(A),\lambda=-$tr$(A).$
Why does $\lambda = -$tr$( A)$ appear, which contradicts the previous statement?
Is there a problem with my understanding or my thinking? Please correct me.

have you tried using the fact that the dinension of the kernel of A is equal to the number of eigenvector of eigenvalue 0 together with the fact that similar matrives have equal trace?

If $tr(A)$ and $-tr(A)$ are both eigen values, then the rank of $A$ won't be $1$.

$\lambda^3 - \lambda Tr(A)^2 = 0$ says that $\lambda$ is either $Tr(A)$, $-Tr(A)$ or $0$, but you cannot be sure it will take all of those values. Notice that if you use the same line of reasoning with $A^{n+1}$ you will find that $\lambda$ can be $0$ or $\omega_n^k Tr(A)$ for any integer $k$, where $\omega_n$ is a $n$-th root of unity

In other words, the λ I calculated in this way is not necessarily the eigenvalue, right?

If $AX = \lambda X$, then $A = \lambda I$ and $A$ is not rank 1.
